# A problem occurred configuring root project 'android' in flutter

Tags: flutter

I got an error while running the flutter app.
The error is

```
**A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Acer\.gradle\caches\jars-9\77f1b6119df996df354847f2f9be857a\gradle-7.1.2.jar.**
```

How to fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to create JAR file for gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426116/not-able-to-create-jar-file-for-gradle-project)

Comment: Delete  ~/.gradle directory and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

there might be a Firewall blocking the connection of Android Studio.
try to disable it for a brief moment and test again. If it works then add Android Studio to your firewall whitelist.